# Quickblox: SDK location not found

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, chat, quickblox

I have imported the sample chat app from Quickblox. The sdk.dir is in place in the local.properties, but I ma receiving the below error:

```
Gradle 'sample-chat' project refresh failed
Error:SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

Anyone has any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I have the same issue: Dozens of projects on my machine, all point to the same SDK location, all work. Downloaded and tried to build the exact same sample from Quickblox and received the exact same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see this error relates to Android SDK location, not to particular library such as QuickBlox. Just set Android API level for your project in settings.
For more information refer to https://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what is going on and it is related to what @Darya said. If you look at the `build.gradle` of the `sample-chat` module you will see the following lines (among others)

```
android {    
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVersion
    }
}
```

Here the SDK versions are defined in terms of the versions used by the root project. If you give a look at the [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html), `rootProject` defines a scope where properties can be found, which is the Project itself.
If you import just the `sample-chat` into Android Studio then those lines are telling Gradle to look for the properties in the same project in where you're defining it, so it's the equivalent of an illegal self reference/definition.

As @Darya mentioned, one solution is to change those definitions to something that makes sense, like:

```
android {    
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
}
```

or you can import the `quickblox-android-sdk` project instead. After doing this the `rootProject` variable will be pointing to this project and will read the properties from the `build.gradle` of the project instead of the one inside the `sample-chat` module.